# Client is not authorized for this domain

Tags: adobe-embed-api

We are using Adobe PDF embed api to display pfs files in our website

I have created the api key in adobe website. It displays de pdf file content but then it stops showing it

I'm getting this error on jwt authentication . I have created the right api key and the right domain but it is still not working.

{"reason":"UNAUTHORIZED_CLIENT","message":"Client is not authorized for this domain"}

I've crated different projects but it is still not working

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geKld.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a client id that uses the same host as where you will use the Embed. If this is not enough to help, please provide some code.